# Multitable joining in Sql

Tags: sql, mysql, select, left-join

I am a beginner trying to build very simple inventory system using PHP + SQL
I have 2 warehouse. I added 2 tables, 1 for each warehouse contains (item id)-(in)- (out) like shown below

table1

| item id | in | out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 10 | 0 |
| item1 | 5 | 0 |
| item2 | 0 | 3 |
| item2 | 0 | 2 |

table2

| item id | in | out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 12 | 0 |
| item1 | 50 | 0 |
| item2 | 0 | 10 |
| item2 | 0 | 30 |

I have report show balance for each warehouse separately by using query below

```
Select item_id, sum(in-out) as balance
from table1
group by item_id
```

like below

| item id | balance |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | 2 |
| item2 | 20 |

My question is how show each warehouse balance in one table like below

| item id | warehouse1 | warehouse2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 7 | 2 |
| item2 | 3 | 20 |

I tired with this query but I get wrong results

```
SELECT table1.item_id,
       sum(table1.in) - sum(table1.out) as tb1,
       sum(table2.in) - sum(table2.out) as tb2
FROM table1,
     table2
WHERE table1.item_id = table2.item_id
GROUP by item_id
```

the query above have 2 problems

1. results are not correct
2. only items in both tables are shown , while any item exist in table and not exists in the second one is not shown

Comment: For a start, don’t have separate tables for each warehouse (just one of the many reasons for not doing this would be the need to create a new table each time there was a new warehouse). Instead have one table with a warehouse_id column

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of serious design flaws in your inventory system.

Firstly, you should have only a single table containing both warehouses, with a `warehouse_id` column.

Second, this is clearly a table of inventory in and out. It makes no sense to have separate columns, you may as well have a single column, where `out` is negative.

| warehouse_id | item_id | qty_moved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item1 | 10 |
| 1 | item1 | 5 |
| 1 | item2 | -3 |
| 1 | item2 | -2 |
| 2 | item1 | 12 |
| 2 | item1 | 50 |
| 2 | item2 | -10 |
| 2 | item2 | -30 |

Now you can just do a simple query with conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
  im.item_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 1 THEN qty_moved END) AS warehouse1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 2 THEN qty_moved END) AS warehouse2
FROM InventoryMove im
GROUP BY
  im.item_id;
```

Comment: thanks a lot to you , as I told I am a beginner and this is my first app ..... I will work on your advice in future ..regards

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the sum (like you did for your first table) for both tables, then join the results together on item_id.

If you can guarantee that both warehouses will have the exact same unique list of item_ids then you can do an INNER JOIN. I've assumed that they may have some discrepancies, so I've opted for a FULL JOIN. However, It seems that MySQL doesn't support the FULL JOIN option. So I've taken the UNION of the LEFT JOIN and the RIGHT JOIN to achieve the desired result.

I've quoted the IN and OUT columns with backticks, as IN is a SQL keyword (not sure about OUT, best to be safe). That way they will be treated as column names and not whatever else they mean (i.e. IN is an operator).

First, setup some tables to mimic your data.

```
-- Create table corresponding to warehouse 1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS warehouse1;
CREATE TABLE warehouse1(item_id CHAR(5) NOT NULL
                    , `in` BIGINT  NOT NULL
                    , `out` BIGINT NOT NULL
                    );
  
INSERT INTO warehouse1(item_id
                    , `in`
                    , `out`
                    )
VALUES('item1', 10, 0)
    , ('item1', 5, 0)
    , ('item2', 0, 3)
    , ('item2', 0, 2);

-- Create table corresponding to warehouse 2
CREATE TABLE warehouse2(item_id CHAR(5) NOT NULL
                    , `in` BIGINT  NOT NULL
                    , `out` BIGINT NOT NULL
                    );
                    
INSERT INTO warehouse2(item_id
                    , `in`
                    , `out`
                    )
VALUES('item1', 12, 0)
    , ('item1', 50, 0)
    , ('item2', 0, 10)
    , ('item2', 0, 30);
```

Secondly, perform the aggregations and join the results.

```
-- Compute the sums for each table, grouped by the item_id and join them together
-- We want a FULL JOIN here. But MySQL doesn't support it, so we UNION a LEFT and a RIGHT
-- to get the same effect.
SELECT wh1.item_id AS item_id
    , wh1.balance AS warehouse1_balance
    , wh2.balance AS warehouse2_balance
FROM(
    SELECT item_id
        , SUM(`in` - `out`) AS balance
    FROM warehouse1
    GROUP BY item_id
    ) wh1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT item_id
        , SUM(`in` - `out`) AS balance
    FROM warehouse2
    GROUP BY item_id
    ) wh2
    ON wh1.item_id = wh2.item_id

UNION

SELECT wh2.item_id AS item_id
    , wh1.balance AS warehouse1_balance
    , wh2.balance AS warehouse2_balance
FROM(
    SELECT item_id
        , SUM(`in` - `out`) AS balance
    FROM warehouse1
    GROUP BY item_id
    ) wh1
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT item_id
        , SUM(`in` - `out`) AS balance
    FROM warehouse2
    GROUP BY item_id
    ) wh2
    ON wh1.item_id = wh2.item_id
;
```

I have deliberately used UNION instead of UNION ALL as both the LEFT JOIN and the RIGHT JOIN will contain the INNER JOIN. So we don't want to include the INNER JOIN twice.

Try it yourself: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YN6aADlQ)

Comment: more efficient to use UNION ALL and make one of the subqueries an anti join (e.g. add `WHERE wh1.item_id IS NULL` to the right join)

Comment: Good point, I felt a little dirty using the UNION.

Comment: You are welcome. Whilst my answer does address your actual question, I'd suggest you heed the advice in Charlieface's answer. If you do use my answer, please take note of ysth's comment, regarding the performance improvement.